# solr search in multiple fields

Tags: 7, search

Now apachesolr search works only in content. It also have to work on other fields 
for eg: on typing "test", It searches only in content.

My requirement is  to search on description,label also (which i have already indexed).
`content:abcd OR description:sample_upload_document`
Using  **apachesolr.api.php**,I tried hook_apachesolr_query_prepare($query)

```
function MYMODULE_apachesolr_query_prepare(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {

     $query->addParam('qf','content description');
     watchdog('solr result',print_r($query,true));

}
```

refering to the site`http://knackforge.com/blog/selvam/drupal-7-filtering-solr-results`.
After performing that, i found description is added to

```
SolrBaseQuery Object
    (
        [params:protected] => Array
            (
                 [qf] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => content^40
                        [1] => description
                    )
```

But still when i give the value for description, search results would not yield any value.

Am i correct in a way? why doesnt it return the result?

How to do that? default search,searches the given text only in content.How to make it to search on other fields like description,label?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Search Api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api)  Module

> This module provides a framework for easily creating searches on any
>   entity known to Drupal, using any kind of search engine. For site
>   administrators, it is a great alternative to other search solutions,
>   since it already incorporates facetting support and the ability to use
>   the Views module for displaying search results, filters, etc. Also,
>   with the Apache Solr integration, a high-performance search engine is
>   available for this module.

Using It you could create *index* for the field you choose!!